# Manually assign Browser to test in visual studio load test

Tags: visual-studio-2010, testing, load, load-testing, performance-testing

Visual Studio 2010 has the ability to run test scripts using different browser profiles. For a specific scenario with two scripts (script1 and script2) you can configure the Browser Mix to run 50% of your scripts as IE7 users and 50% of your scripts as mobile users.

The problem I am facing is that the mobile and desktop versions of a web site are completely different. So the same script that is recorded for the desktop will not run for the mobile. I cannot see any configuration or way to force script1 to only run as IE7 and script2 to only run as safari for iphone.

This is possible with many other performance tools but I fear given the simplicity of MSVS Load testing it may not be possible. Does anyone know if this is possible, the only way I can think that it might be is if somehow in each script I can override the browser mix setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer. I was trying to add a desktop browser only test and a mobile only test to the same scenario. The key here is to create a separate scenario within the existing "load test" and have one just for desktop browser tests and one just for mobile tests, as demonstrated in the following picture, where the "Web Test" scenario will be split between IE7 and Firefox3, while the "Mobile" scenario will just run on a smartphone.

[image: scenario]